# How to write publish notes on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, desktop-application

I am using ClickOnce deployment to publish my application on Visual Studio 2010, but I also want to write some upgrade notes about every publish. Is it possible to write publish notes on the project property screen?

If not, is there a third-party solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the ClickOnce system on Windows, but for sure you can do this from your code after your application is launched. You can use [ApplicationDeployment.IsFirstRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property which is true after first run and after update.